# Exchange Web Services (EWS) delete a RequiredAttendees from a meeting?

Tags: xml, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

how I can delete a user from a meeting with XML?

I have this code that delete all RequiredAttendees

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy" ConflictResolution="AutoResolve" SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy" 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <ItemChanges>
        <t:ItemChange>
          <t:ItemId Id="AAALAGVkaUB...=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAA...."/>
          <t:Updates>
            <t:DeleteItemField>
              <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:RequiredAttendees"/>
            </t:DeleteItemField>
          </t:Updates>
        </t:ItemChange>
      </ItemChanges>
    </UpdateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and this code to add a RequiredAttendee

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy" ConflictResolution="AutoResolve" SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy" 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <ItemChanges>
        <t:ItemChange>
          <t:ItemId Id="AAALAGVkaUBlbGl...." ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAC......"/>
          <t:Updates>
                    <t:AppendToItemField>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:RequiredAttendees" />
          <t:CalendarItem>
            <t:RequiredAttendees>
              <t:Attendee>
                <t:Mailbox>
                  <t:EmailAddress>user@localhost.comm</t:EmailAddress>
                </t:Mailbox>
              </t:Attendee>
            </t:RequiredAttendees>
          </t:CalendarItem>
        </t:AppendToItemField>
          </t:Updates>
        </t:ItemChange>
      </ItemChanges>
    </UpdateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

both work perfectly for me, but I can not find a way to delete one used from the meeting and not all!

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/e467f0ea-76d5-44c0-ad9d-36fb000d7830) looks promising. Instead of being able to remove attendees, it seems that you have to update the attendees list with just the people you want.

You could also use the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633620%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

Comment: i'm not using C# for this one, and I need it in XML :-(

Comment: thanks, that looks very interesting it does make sense :-) so this is only this way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe so. Seems so silly not to have a simple remove utility. =/

Comment: still it is OK to use this one, it kind of making things easier, in my code that builds the XML :-)